# Why an emission object behind a glass object lost its emission property

Tags: shaders

Why does the emission object behind a glass shader object loses its emission property, you can see it does not appear in the emit pass.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because emission pass contains only emissive rays hitting camera directly.

Glass (even transparent) is technically a surface blocking the ray and what you see in render is transmission.

So for emission behind a glass check **Transmission > Indirect pass**.

Comment: great help thanks a lot

Comment: Great, it seems your Q is helpfull for others too :)